# Get URL from an item

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, url

I'm building a list in which I can transform my item in project, but in my project, I'd like to have a direct url to my list

So I added a calculated colum :

```
=CONCATENATE("SharepointSite/ListName/DispForm.aspx?ID=",ID)
```

But as I understood, the ID is given once the item is created, so my list won't have the ID for newly created items.

So I'd like to know if there is a direct way to get my item url?

I'm using Sharepoint Online.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID value will be updated only after the item is created successfully in the list, so that using ID in the calculated columns is not good option.

As a workaround, we can retrieve ID value using the workflow. Automatically start the Workflow when the item is created, get the ID from the current item and then connect strings.

Comment: Ok thank you
I built a workflow on flow and now it's working